# Cannot borrow `counts` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, hashmap, borrow-checker

I'm getting this error

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `counts` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:13:64
   |
13 |             counts.entry(x).or_insert(cmp::max(current_count, *counts.get(&x).unwrap()));
   |             --------------- ---------                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |             |               |
   |             |               mutable borrow later used by call
   |             mutable borrow occurs here
```

but I can't seem to understand what's wrong despite having seen a few other questions asking about the same error and they are using `slice` instead of dealing with a `HashMap` like here.

The 2nd argument of `cmp::max` has to be a value, but I cant figure out how to make use of an mutable borrow here as suggested by the compiler.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cmp;

fn main() {
  let data: Vec<u8> = vec![1,1,3,1,1];
    
  let mut counts = HashMap::new();
  let mut current_count = 0;
  for (i, &x) in data.iter().enumerate() {
    if i > 0 {
        if x == data[i-1] {
            current_count += 1;
            counts.entry(x).or_insert(cmp::max(current_count, *counts.get(&x).unwrap()));
        } else {
            current_count = 0;
        }
    }
  }
  
  println!("{:?}", counts);
}
```

---

@BallpointBen I think this might work, but not sure if this is a good way.

```
  for (i, &x) in data.iter().enumerate() {
    if i > 0 {
        if x == data[i-1] {
            current_count += 1;
            counts.entry(x).or_insert(1);
            counts.insert(x, cmp::max(current_count, counts[&x]));
        } else {
            current_count = 0;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: [`HashMap::entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) mutably borrows `self`, so it is impossible to do `HashMap::get` there. One solution is to store the value to be inserted before the `counts.entry(x).or_insert(...)` line.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get a map of key => longest consecutive run?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes thats correct!

Comment: @BallpointBen I think I have to first do a `counts.entry(x).or_insert(1)` to ensure that the key exists, then update its value using `counts.insert(x, cmp::max(current_count, counts[&x]))` but I'm unsure if this is idiomatic. Updated question to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

[`HashMap::entry()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) borrows the map mutably for the whole life of the returned [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html). You cannot use the map until you finish with the entry.

The fix is simple - first retrieve the value into a variable, then call `entry()`:

```rust
let v = *counts.get(&x).unwrap();
counts
    .entry(x)
    .or_insert(cmp::max(current_count, v));
```

You cannot use [`or_insert_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with) by that, which would be preferred, but you didn't use it anyway.

However, what you're trying to do is not good: when will your `or_insert()` be needed? Only when there is no value associated with this key in the map, so trying to `get().unwrap()` it is always going to panic!

Comment: I would stress the second part of the answer more - while it is possible to make the code compile, it doesn't really make much sense so is unlikely to have the behaviour OP intended.

Comment: @apilat Agree. I think I had to first do a `counts.entry(x).or_insert(1)` to ensure that the key exists,  then update its value using `counts.insert(x, cmp::max(current_count, counts[&x]))` but I'm unsure if this is idiomatic

Comment: @gameveloster `counts.entry(x).or_insert(1)` returns a mutable reference to the value. I think the idiomatic solution would be to then update it using `*val = cmp::max(current_count, *val)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that meshes well with the type system. We append a `None` to the end of the iterator to signal that we're done (roughly equivalent to an `if i == my_vec.len()-1` check but without needing a `Vec`)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

fn longest_run<T: Hash + Eq>(items: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> HashMap<T, usize> {
    let mut runs = HashMap::new();
    let mut items = items.into_iter();

    let mut prev = match items.next() {
        Some(x) => x,
        None => return runs,
    };

    let mut curr_count = 1;

    for item in items.map(Some).chain(std::iter::once(None)) {
        if let Some(item) = item {
            if item == prev {
                curr_count += 1;
            } else {
                let prev_count = runs.entry(prev).or_insert(1);
                *prev_count = (*prev_count).max(curr_count);
                curr_count = 1;
            }

            prev = item;
        } else {
            let prev_count = runs.entry(prev).or_insert(1);
            *prev_count = (*prev_count).max(curr_count);

            // Redundant, but needed to tell the compiler it's
            // ok to move prev into `entry` without
            // reinitializing it, as we won't need it again
            break;
        }
    }

    runs
}

fn main() {
    for v in vec![
        vec![],
        vec![1],
        vec![1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        vec![1, 2],
        vec![1, 1, 2, 1],
        vec![1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        vec![1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    ] {
        println!("{:?}: {:?}", v, longest_run(v.iter().copied()));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
[]: {}
[1]: {1: 1}
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]: {1: 5}
[1, 2]: {2: 1, 1: 1}
[1, 1, 2, 1]: {1: 2, 2: 1}
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]: {2: 3, 1: 4}
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]: {2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 5}
```